# Video trim in hour:minute:second:millisecond format

Tags: video-editor

I'm trying to trim a video in hour:minute:second:millisecond
format. But I use this command

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 01.02.26.060 -i R.mp4 -to 01.02.28.785 -map 0 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 out.mp4
```

and i got this message

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
  configuration: --arch=armeabi-v7a --as=arm-linux-androideabi-clang --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-clang --cxx=arm-linux-androideabi-clang++ --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-static --disable-symver --enable-cross-compile --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libvpx --enable-shared --enable-libsoxr --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwebp --prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr --target-os=android --extra-libs=-landroid-glob --enable-neon
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Invalid duration specification for ss: 01.02.26.060
```

What changes do I need to trim video in Hour:Minute:second:millisecond
format?

Answer (score 1):

For time marks try: `"01:02:26.060"`, `"01:02:28.785"`

(hour:minute:second.millisecond)